# How Can I Deserialize this JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have been trying to deserilize a JSON object to C# class. My JSON Objetc (when I have read it from Request.InputStream) is the following:

```
{  
   "accion":"Guardar",
   "ejercicio":"2017",
   "codigoPieza":"13",
   "solicitado":"61",
   "solicitante":"46",
   "listadoMeses":{  
      "Enero":{  
         "valor":"1",
         "almacenado":"false"
      },
      "Febrero":{  
         "valor":"",
         "almacenado":"true"
      },
      "Mayo":{  
         "valor":"2",
         "almacenado":"true"
      },
      "Agosto":{  
         "valor":"2",
         "almacenado":"true"
      },
      "Noviembre":{  
         "valor":"2",
         "almacenado":"true"
      }
   }
}
```

This deserialize correctly if I have this class:

```
public class RespuestaUsuario
{
        public string accion { get; set; }
        public string ejercicio { get; set; }
        public string codigoPieza { get; set; }
        public string solicitado { get; set; }
        public string solicitante { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> listadoMeses { get; set; }
    }
```

But I want to use this classes:

```
public class RespuestaUsuario
{
    public string accion { get; set; }
    public string ejercicio { get; set; }
    public string codigoPieza { get; set; }
    public string solicitado { get; set; }
    public string solicitante { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Mes> listadoMeses { get; set; }
}

public class Mes
{
    string valor;
    string almacenado;
}
```

Sadly, if I use the last code, the dictionary have one item for each (string key) month (each iteration of listadoMeses), but each instance for **Mes** class has both properties **NULL**.

How could I do with the last classes?

The code I use to Deserialize is the following (but this information, I suppose, is useless, because on both cases are the same):

```
System.IO.Stream str = Request.InputStream;
str.Position = 0;
string datos = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(str, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    datos = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

JavaScriptSerializer serializador = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RespuestaUsuario respuesta = (RespuestaUsuario)serializador.Deserialize<RespuestaUsuario>(datos);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your properties on *Mes* class are private. Add the **public** access modifier to the properties.

Change it to this:

```
public class Mes
{
    public string valor;
    public string almacenado;
}
```

Comment: No. The OP code does not include an access modifier for the fields on `Mes` class. By default, a field declared on a class without an access modifier, is interpreted as private. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Comment: But the code has the public modifier from the begining. On the following link you can see how from begining the class Mes has the PUBLIC modifier access:

 
[stackoverflow.com/posts/40533428/revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40533428/revisions)

Comment: Even on the link you provide, `Mes` IS public, but the fields `valor` and `almacenado` on `Mes` doesn't have any modifier, just `string valor;`

Comment: You're right, class access modifier was public but no properties modifier. So, by default, the properties were **private** and this made Serialize doesn't work fine.

I have change properties modifier and now it works. I knew properties must be public in order to get a correct work of Serialize, but for the subclass Mes, I had forgotten write them.

Thank you so much, now works just I like. **THANK YOU**

(Sorry if my english isn't very good)

Answer (score 2):

I don't like JavaScriptSerializer, I much prefer to use Json.net from newtonsoft

This can be obtained via nu get:

```
> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Newtonsoft.Json**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/). Here how your class should look like !

```
public class Enero
{
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string almacenado { get; set; }
}

public class Febrero
{
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string almacenado { get; set; }
}

public class Mayo
{
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string almacenado { get; set; }
}

public class Agosto
{
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string almacenado { get; set; }
}

public class Noviembre
{
    public string valor { get; set; }
    public string almacenado { get; set; }
}

public class ListadoMeses
{
    public Enero Enero { get; set; }
    public Febrero Febrero { get; set; }
    public Mayo Mayo { get; set; }
    public Agosto Agosto { get; set; }
    public Noviembre Noviembre { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string accion { get; set; }
    public string ejercicio { get; set; }
    public string codigoPieza { get; set; }
    public string solicitado { get; set; }
    public string solicitante { get; set; }
    public ListadoMeses listadoMeses { get; set; }
}
```

How you deserialize the json to object.

```
RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Here  [**Dotnet Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G0YBTU)

Comment: Probably because this does not answer the question. Your suggestion is to completely change the class structure and the serializer library.

Comment: @thepirat000 probably because with this class structure he need to write custom parser ?